# $\mathbb R$ is not isometric with $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

show that $\mathbb R$ is not isometric with $\mathbb R^2$ (with the usual metrics). I want to use the first definition of continuity (i.e. the $\epsilon $ -$\delta$ stuff) but I don't see a way to proceed. I guess the contrapositive? Thanks

Comment: It is not at all clear what you intend to do with epsilons and deltas. I doubt one can do anything useful, in fact.

Comment: I didn't have a plan of action aside from using the definition I have from class that involves $\epsilon$ , $\delta $ and the two metrics. It says: Two metric spaces are isometric if there exists an f function that is 1-1 and  onto from M into N such that if $\rho$ is the metric on M and $\omicron$ is the metric on N then $\rho( x,y) = \omicron (f(x),f(y))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An isometry between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ would imply a contradiction. Consider that any one point separates $\mathbb R$ , but does not separate/disconnect $\mathbb R^2$. If h:$\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ were a homeomorphism between the two, then, for any $x$ in $\mathbb R$ , h':$\mathbb R-{x}\rightarrow \mathbb R^2-h(x)$ would also be a homeomorphism. But this is not possible, since $\mathbb R-{x}$ is disconnected , but $\mathbb R^2-h(x)$ is not.

Maybe to be more precise, if there was a continuous bijection h (an isometry) between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ , then the following contradiction would result:

Consider the restriction h' of h to $[-1,1]$ . By compactness of [-1,1], and by $\mathbb R^2$ being Hausdorff (so that its subspace h'([-1,1]) is Hausdorff ), we have a continuous bijection between compact and Hausdorff, so that $h'([-1,1])\rightarrow h'([-1,1])$ is a homeomorphism. By connectedness of [-1,1] and since h' is injective (and h is a continuous bijection into $\mathbb R^2$), the image contains an open ball. Now , since h' is a homeomorphism, it sends its interior (-1,1) into the interior of the image, which is connected , but we have the issue of the cutsets.

Comment: Could you please tell me how an isometry imply homeomorphism?

Comment: Sorry, I was being loose; I was trying to do something like this: take [-1,1] in $\mathbb R$. Since it is compact, its image (as a continuous bijection from compact into Hausdorff) would be a homeomorphism into h([-1,1]). Then we consider the interior (-1,1)--the reals--, which would be sent to the interior of h([-1,1]). And then I would apply the idea in the post: (-1,1) has a singleton as a cutset, but, by connectedness, h(-1,1) does not.

Comment: I do not understand your point

Comment: O.K: The assumption of the existence of a continuous bijection bet. $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ leads to the following contradiction: assume there is such a continuous bijection h. Consider the restriction h|_[-1,1]; h, restricted to [-1,1] is a continuous bijection between a compact space and a Hausdorff space, so that h':[-1,1]->h([-1,1]) is a homeomorphism. Then, by connectedness of [-1,1], f([-1,1]) is connected, so that (by injection of h) it contains an open ball.

Comment: Now, the interior (-1,1) maps into the interior of the image. But (-1,1) has a singleton as a cutset, but the image does not have a singleton as a cutset.

Comment: I know that there is no continous bijection, but I asked you something else.

Comment: I'm assuming an isometry is a continuous bijection (whose inverse may not be continuous). Yes, I admitted I had been loose; I should have said ( and I edited my post to reflect this; let me re-edit) that the existence of this continuous bijection would lead to a contradiction; not to the conclusion that R and R^2 are homeomorphic. My apologies; it is 3 a.m here, and I must go. I will come back tomorrow rto answer any other question. Sorry.

Answer (score 30):

In $\mathbb R$ there do not exist three distinct points such that the distance between each pair is equal to $1$.

On the other hand, in $\mathbb R^2$ there do exist equilateral triangles.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: nice answer :) :)

Answer (score 0):

For a general argument, one can say that Hausdorff dimension is an isometric invariant and that $\dim_H(\mathbb{R}^n)=n$. Therefore, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are isometric iff $m=n$.

(Of course, here Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's answer is really better.)